# Installing two Ubuntu VMs on VMware

Tags: 20.04, virtualization, vmware-workstation, multiple-workstations

So I need to install two ubuntu VMs on my Windows Machine in VMWare. Do I have to download two separate installers i.e the .exe file for downloading and running two machines or can I just use the same installer for both the VMs?

Comment: There is no `.exe` involved while installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine. Did you mean ISO/disc image?

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant ISO/disk image.

Comment: I've already installed the first VM, I want to know if I need another ISO/disk image for the second VM of if I can use the first one.

Comment: You can reuse that ISO. Related question: [Can I use the same Windows 10 ISO image multiple times? I had used it once in VirtualBox and now I am trying to use that again in VirtualBox.](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-the-same-Windows-10-ISO-image-multiple-times-I-had-used-it-once-in-VirtualBox-and-now-I-am-trying-to-use-that-again-in-VirtualBox)

Comment: Thanks alot! That helps alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to install it a second time.  Just make a copy of the original installation directory.  In fact, you can make as many copies as you like.  When it asks you whether you moved or copied it, say copied.  That way it will give you a different network address.